# Crystal Reports Splitting Page up into Thirds

Tags: crystal-reports

I have been asked to mock up a report in Crystal (i would normally use SSRS but the application uses crystal for report), and i need to split the page up into thirds. The idea is that the top 2 thirds are for the customer, then there will be a tear line on the paper and under that will be the section for us to keep.

What is the best way to accomplish this, baring in mind the report could go over 2 pages?

Cheers
Luke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding of the requirements, you just want to space things out over a customer's order (or something similar).  I am assuming the grouping will be by customer with items in the details sections.

1)  If all fields required are in a single records, and you can stick by the "2/3's page" visually, you can force the spacing simply by extending the reporting band sections.  i.e., Increase the page header and include some customer information, or do the same with a group header, etc.   and then space out a single details band with fields spread out as is visually pleasing.
With the spacing done this way, you can also embed a small band that holds only a dashed line, which will be a visual tear line.
Fields placed in the next band will be the portion that you intend to keep.

2)  If the customer section will have multiple items in details -- be smaller or larger (i.e., if you are pulling in an inventory list that may have 1 or 21 items), then you can still something similar, but not using enlarged, fixed band sizes.  You can put customer general information in a group header, followed by multiple details (records), and end with a two-band group footer.  The first band can be any closing information for that customer, followed with a visual tear-bar, and the last band can be the information you wish to keep.
Grouping by customer and forcing new pages for each customer should give you what you're looking for.

I hope that's clear enough to give you two alternatives.

D'Oh... and, forgot to include:  You can use the Section Expert to format a group footer to Print At the Bottom Of Page, forcing the portion that you want to keep to the lower part of the page.  On a multi-page printout, it would be forced to the bottom of the nth page.